# Controller @RequestMapping URL returning 404 not found

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build a simple Spring based Web Application using Tomcat server. When I try to test if my controller is working by creating a URL endpoint, I get a HTTP 404 error upon sending a GET request that endpoint.

The base URL is "http://localhost:8080/assignment2/"

I'm trying to set up an endpoint on "/trafficameras"

The requestMapping method in the controller class is defined as

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/trafficcameras", params = {"ip_comm_status", "camera_status"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String parse(@RequestParam(value="ip_comm_status", required=false) String ip_comm_status_val, @RequestParam(value="camera_status", required=false) String camera_status_val)
    {

        return "Result is:";
    }
```

When I try to send a GET request to "http://localhost:8080/assignment2/trafficcameras", instead of outputting "Result is:",
I get:

```
HTTP 404: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

My web.xml file is defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Spring Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servletContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The beans are defined in servletContext.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean name="cameraController" class="TrafficCamerasController">
        <constructor-arg ref="trafficCamerasServiceImpl"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean name="trafficCamerasServiceImpl" class="TrafficCamerasServiceImpl" />


</beans>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I've been scratching my head for a few hours now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/trafficcameras", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String parse(@RequestParam(value="ip_comm_status", required=false) String ip_comm_status_val, @RequestParam(value="camera_status", required=false) String camera_status_val)
{
    return "Result is:";
}
```

Comment: or use @PathVariable for the GET Request